# Create package for large table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a very large table that is created programmatically, and needs to be shipped to be added to a SQL Server database at a remote site.

What is the best way to do this?

The table may contain hundreds of thousands of pretty short records, and its contents need to be added to an existing table.

Comment: What versions of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: SSIS or c# etc as a tool/client?

Comment: SQL servers 2005 and 2008.
The tool I'm building with is in VB.net.
The aim is to not require anything on the client to open the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bulkcopy the data, zip it if necessary - and insert it with bulkcopy at the destination. This should require absolutely nothing extra at the destination site - and if the recieving party can't be trusted to run a bulkcopy in a command-line, a simple .NET executable could be written to do the job.

Comment: @Shahar If you have had problems with bulkcopy, has that been on the source or destination-side? And have you tried working with batchsizes when importing at the destination? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188267.aspx

Comment: The problems with bulk copy were in a different environment, where multiple threads were adding to the same table at once. I implemented it here, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without specific details on the fields of you table it sounds as though a simple export to CSV (using your own code or SSIS) should do. You could always compress the data before it is sent if you are transmitting it electronically.

Your VB.net tool can execute the SQL to create the table in the destination database and then load the rows simply by performing `INSERT` statements. It won't be fast but it would achieve your goal of not requiring any special tools, only your app.

<strike>I'm not sure you will find a solution which packages everything in to one file and requires no client set-up unless you look at using a purchased tool such as [Redgate's SQL Packager](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-packager/).</strike> I take that back, see "Edit 2" below.

My vote would be to buy the Redgate tool, for what it costs how long is it going to take you to develop & test a solution which will provide a single `exe` containing your schema and data?

**EDIT:** You should investigate the [BCP tool and BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196743%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) statements too.

**EDIT 2:** An alternative method is available which I have only just found out about, the Database Publishing Wizard. It can generate a SQL script to create the table then insert the data. Sure, it's going to be a big SQL script but at least you would not have to create any program or install anything on the client machine as you are sending them a text file.

You should have it installed, search for `SqlPubWiz.exe` and [here's an example of using it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/06/24/sql-server-2008-r2-generating-insert-statements-for-a-table.aspx).

Comment: We tried the SQL insert approach in the past, but the file is too large, and it fails.

Comment: The fields are strings and integers.
We can't use a purchased tool, because it would require installation on computers which are not under our control.
We have experience with BCP and BULK INSERT, but it also cannot handle well this many records.

Comment: I believe Redgate's tool does not require any installation on the client's machine, it produces a single executable which is run to create the schema and import the data. They do a 14 day trial so why not give it a go? BTW I have no affiliation to Redgate and do not benefit from sales of their products, I just think they make some good SQL tools.

Comment: I'm also interested to know more about how `BULK INSERT` has failed to move your data, as that's what it's designed to do :) Seriously though I've used SSIS to insert 32 million rows from a SQL RAW file in a few minutes, what went wrong with your package? You may have needed to set the `BATCH SIZE` parameter of the command.

Comment: regarding Redgate's tool, the problem is that the source computers are varied and dispersed, not the target. I sort of misled you there.
As for bulk insert, see my comment to Anders's answer.